# How to check if the request param of GET request is valid? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to check if in the GET request (this is GET request) there is only customer id provided and not other parameters. How should I check this in the current context and which is the exception that I should return?

```
public JObject GetStatus(GetStatusRequest request)
{
    var responseArr = new JArray();
    var customers = GetCustomers(request.CustomerId);

    foreach (var c in customers)
    {
        responseArr.Add(FormatRequest(customers));
    }

    return new JObject
    {
        ["customers"] = responseArr
    };
}
```

Comment: Because of some requirement that was given. And it is if there are some other request params than this to return bad request.

Comment: Presumably this is some variant of ASP.Net (but "plain" or Core)? Or maybe it's using some other web framework? Please edit your question and add another tag so we know what you're working with.

Comment: No, I am using .NET Core framework

Comment: Yes, so add the [tag:asp.net-core] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using asp.net core 2.1 I'd do it like so...

```
public class CustomerListResponse {
    public List<YourCustomerClassName> Customers {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult<CustomerListResponse> GetStatus(GetStatusRequest request)
{
    // check request
    if(doyourcheckhere == false) {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // load your data here. Do not think in JArray and JObject
    // simply use POCOs
    var customers = GetCustomers(request.CustomerId);

    // if you need to reformat, create separate class and use e.g. automapper

    return new CustomerListResponse {
        Customers = customers
    };
}
```

Comment: While this probably the bets choice if you HAVE to use `GetStatusRequest` to get `CustomerId`. If your controller action only cares about `CustomerId`, then the only parameter it should accept is `CustromerId`. Any other additional data is outside the responsibility of this particular controller action. It is a violation of SOLID principles.

Try to make your controller `public IActionResult GetStatus(int CustomerId) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetStatus(GetStatusRequest request)
    {
       try
       {
          if (request.CustomerId>0 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Customername) /*&& other conditions*/)
          {
             var customers = GetCustomers(request.CustomerId);

             return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customers );
          }
          else 
          {
               return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Your custom error message here");
          }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new HttpError(ex.Message));
       }
    }
```